# Bootstrap Modal - Unable to collect attr from relatedTarget?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I have a PHP loop that creates a series of buttons with unique data attributes. When these buttons are clicked they open a modal which collects the values of the data attributes on the button, and uses them to prepopulate the form. Can be seen here: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/javascript/#modals-related-target

The modal opens, but doesn't display the data I'm trying to collect. I also cannot get core functions such as `alert();` to work.. and I'm lost.

I have tried using jQuery's data() and the relevant data attributes, but when they also didn't work I stuck to using attr().

Can anyone help?

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-info" data-toggle="modal" id="ABC-1" data-clientcode="VCDE" data-checkid="7" data-checkname="Check 1" data-target="#comment-modal">
Add Comment
</button>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-info" data-toggle="modal" id="ABC-2" data-clientcode="VAM" data-checkid="7" data-checkname="Check 2" data-target="#comment-modal">
    Add Comment
    </button>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-info" data-toggle="modal" id="ABC-3" data-clientcode="VAM" data-checkid="7" data-checkname="Check 3" data-target="#comment-modal">
    Add Comment
    </button>

<div id="comment-modal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title check-comment-title" id="myModalLabel"></h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body check-comment-body">
                <label for="clientid" class="control-label">Client ID:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="clientid" disabled="">
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Save Comment</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){

    // This alert doesn't run for some reason. 
    // console.log doesn't work either, but the modal works...
    alert();
    $('#comment-modal').on('show.bs.modal', function(event) {

        var modal = $(this);
        var button = $(event.relatedTarget); // btn that triggered the modal
        var client = button.attr('data-clientcode');
        var checkid = button.attr('data-checkid');
        var checkname = button.attr('data-checkname');

        modal.find('.modal-title').text('Comment submission for ' + client)
        modal.find('.modal-body .check-comment-body').html(checkname);
        modal.find('.modal-body input').val(checkid);
    )}
});
</script>
```

Comment: There may be other script errors, open developer console in browser and see if there are any errors.

Comment: I don't know why I didn't see that... wow. There is another error: vendors.bundle.js:3869 Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'createLinearGradient' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': The provided double value is non-finite. I'll look in to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you have an error in your code. Try this:

```js
$(function(){

    // This alert doesn't run for some reason. 
    // console.log doesn't work either, but the modal works...
    
    $('#comment-modal').on('show.bs.modal', function(event) {

        var modal = $(this);
        var button = $(event.relatedTarget); // btn that triggered the modal
        var client = button.attr('data-clientcode');
        var checkid = button.attr('data-checkid');
        var checkname = button.attr('data-checkname');

        modal.find('.modal-title').text('Comment submission for ' + client)
        modal.find('.modal-body .check-comment-body').html(checkname);
        modal.find('.modal-body input').val(checkid);
    })
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-info" data-toggle="modal" id="ABC-1" data-clientcode="VCDE" data-checkid="7" data-checkname="Check 1" data-target="#comment-modal">
Add Comment
</button>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-info" data-toggle="modal" id="ABC-2" data-clientcode="VAM" data-checkid="8" data-checkname="Check 2" data-target="#comment-modal">
    Add Comment
    </button>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-info" data-toggle="modal" id="ABC-3" data-clientcode="VAM" data-checkid="9" data-checkname="Check 3" data-target="#comment-modal">
    Add Comment
    </button>

<div id="comment-modal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title check-comment-title" id="myModalLabel"></h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body check-comment-body">
                <label for="clientid" class="control-label">Client ID:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="clientid" disabled="">
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Save Comment</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Erick, I'll try this now. What have you changed specifically? I saw the missing semicolon modal.find line, but you haven't added that to yours either... I can't see the change :P sorry!

Comment: On your script you have ")}" but what your really want is "})"

Comment: Thank you, I can't believe I missed that!